# Why we use webpack in react applications

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Actually, I'm just curious as to why webpack is used in react applications. Why do I still use Webpack to create a dist folder with a dist.js file if I can create a build using npm run build?

Can somebody help me with my confusion?

Comment: In your package.json, what does it say under the `bulid` field?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance i didn't implement the webpack. I'm just asking why we use webpack

Comment: General Grievance is trying to point out that `npm run build` doesn't do a build on its own.  It just runs whatever is under scripts/build in your package.json, and that probably IS webpack if you have a look.

Comment: @RichN Thank you for clearing the point. Is webpack comes with react app ?

Comment: No, it's a separate thing.  A 'module bundler'.  There are other module bundlers, like rollup, that people use, but I think webpack is probably the most popular.

Comment: Ok @RichN and what's the purpose of webpack

Comment: You answered that in your question: it takes separate JavaScript files and combines them into one file (dist.js in your case)

Comment: Yes yes. You are not getting my point. If create-react-app work flow is okay then why we setup config webpack to unpack the bundle